# ConnectionStrings in app.config with characters that the .config file doesn't like

Tags: .net, connection-string, app-config, special-characters

I've looked for the answer and can't find it.  It's got to be something obvious and I'm just missing it.

We have a connection string issue in an app.config file.  It uses SQL Server authentication, and the password contains an "&" and a "+" symbol.  Obviously the parsing is going wrong.  Changing the password would be a hassle at this point.  Is there a way to handle this?

[image: partial connection string with sensitive data blocked]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Encode the '&' as '&amp;' - ampersand is a reserved character in XML

More info: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: That did the trick.  It was something obvious.  Thank you, very much!

Comment: And when I google "special characters xml" I find tons of matches.  I was googling things like "special characters app.config" and similar searches.  Duh.  The .config file is just XML.  Need coffee.

Answer (score 10):

Since the web.config is XML, you need to escape the five special characters:

**`&amp;`** -> **`&`** *ampersand, U+0026*
**`&lt;`**  --> **`<`** *left angle bracket, less-than sign, U+003C*
**`&gt;`**  --> **`>`** *right angle bracket, greater-than sign, U+003E*
**`&quot;`**-> **`"`** *quotation mark, U+0022*
**`&apos;`**-> **`'`** *apostrophe, U+0027*

**+** is not a problem, I suppose.

Answer (score 6):

`web.config` is an XML file and XML content needs to be escaped...

Change the `&` to `&amp;` in the password field and you are good to do.

Answer (score 1):

Try encoding the characters. Use `&amp;` for ampersand.